# Why does domain size change results of NDSolve? / How to overcome this?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

this is a follow-up on a previous question which was answered, but it turned out that I was running in circles...

I have the following code:

```
(*Parameters*)eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732;
(*PDEs*)
pde1 := 
  D[pp[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    pp[t, x, y]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x, y] - z[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2));
pde2 := D[z[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    z[t, x, y]*(eps*pp[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2) - m);
(*Initial conditions*)
lo = 22
hi = 25
domlen = 50
ic1[x_, y_] := Which[x > lo && x < hi && y > lo && y < hi, 6, True, 0];
ic2[x_, y_] := Which[x < hi, 1, True, 1/c11];
(*Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary \
conditions*)
{solp, solz} = 
 Monitor[NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2, z[0, x, y] == ic1[x, y], 
    pp[0, x, y] == ic2[x, y]}, {pp, z}, {t, 0, 
    100}, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {domlen, domlen}], 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

which produces certain spatiotemporal patterns.

However, I am not sure wether these patterns result from boundary forcing. Hence, I want to consider a larger domain and check wether these patterns still emerge.

Here is the same code for a larger domain (even the extent of initial conditions is the same).

```
(*Parameters*)eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732;
(*PDEs*)
pde1 := 
  D[pp[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    pp[t, x, y]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x, y] - z[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2));
pde2 := D[z[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    z[t, x, y]*(eps*pp[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2) - m);
(*Initial conditions*)
lo = 2
hi = 5
domlen = 10
ic1[x_, y_] := Which[x > lo && x < hi && y > lo && y < hi, 6, True, 0];
ic2[x_, y_] := Which[x < hi, 1, True, 1/c11];
(*Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary \
conditions*)
{solp, solz} = 
 Monitor[NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2, z[0, x, y] == ic1[x, y], 
    pp[0, x, y] == ic2[x, y]}, {pp, z}, {t, 0, 
    100}, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {domlen, domlen}], 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

Why do I get this error now:

```
NDSolveValue: At t == 56.08186878658157`, step size is effectively zero;
singularity or stiff system suspected
```

To me it does only make sense that Mathematica adjusts the step size to the domain and a larger step size results in this error. Am I right with that? What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. "Here is the same code for a larger domain…" You're using `50` in the first code sample while `10` in the second sample. 2. Just search `MaxCellMeasure` in the document or this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain size for the finite element method does not influence the number of elements in the mesh. That means a larger domain uses the same amount of elements than a smaller domain. If you want the same resolution on both meshes, you'd need to use `MaxCellMeasure` to get that. You can find an overview of the meshing capabilities in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html).